# codeigniter 2.1.3 htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using apache2 on ubuntu 12.10. but the htaccess is not working and here is my htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /ci/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_security.c>
   SecFilterEngine Off
   SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>
```

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php'; 
$config[‘index_page’] = “”;
$config[‘uri_protocol’]  = “AUTO”;
```

```
1 http://localhost/ci/index.php/site/about
2 http://localhost/ci/site/about
```

the first work but i want the second to work any idea how to make it work. thanks

```
404 Not Found
The requested URL /ci/site/about was not found on this server.
```

Comment: try to remove $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php'; to $config['base_url'] = ' '

Comment: still the same error message

Answer (score 0):

**Did you enabled mod rewrite ?**

set your htaccess (sample)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

remove index.php in your config

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; 
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Also allow overriding htaccess in your apache

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

and edit the file & change to

```
AllowOverride All
```

and restart apache

Comment: apache rewritemode is AllowOverride All but i keep getting this The requested URL /ci/site/about was not found on this server.

Comment: try setting your baseurl = ''

Comment: my base url is $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci/index.php'; and still i got the same error messsage

Answer (score 0):

Here is what my setup looks like, and mine works as you like yours to work:

*.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

*config.php*

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/icms/';
```

I think that is all I changed to make mine work.

Hope it helps.

Regards,

Kobus

Comment: thank you Mr kobus for your help but i did like you exactly told me and i keep getting The requested URL /ci/site/about was not found on this server.  apache LOG file [Thu Apr 11 20:10:10 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: /var/www/ci/site

Comment: So, your $config['index_page'] is blank, and the $config['base_url'] equals to 'http://localhost/ci/'. When you go to http://localhost/ci/index.php/site/about, your page works, but when you go to9 http://localhost/ci/site/about, it does not? The only thing left I can think of is that you did not put the .htaccess info in the RIGHT .htaccess file. I have done that before. It must be the one in the root of your site's folder, not the one in the application folder. Besides that, I am sorry, but I do not have any other help then, as mine works as it is there...

Comment: i tried every thing but it's not working, when i try localhost/ci/site/about it display index.php